# How can i fix attempt to present UIAlertController on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uialertview

Im trying to work on alerts as a way to show potential errors while logging in to my app.
I have a couple of alerts in different parts of my code. None of them work. They don't show and print:

> Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I see a lot of different posts with the same problem, they all get fixed by doing something with the `viewDidAppear`. I've tried that, but since its not only one alert and since I use a function to call each alert, that help didn't work.

Here is some code:

```
    func alerts(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Oops...", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if emailField.text == "", pwField.text == "" {
            alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Please fill out the fields.")
            accessGiven = false
        } else {
            accessGiven = true
        }

//        if emailField.text == "", pwField.text != "" || emailField.text != "", pwField.text == "" {
//            alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Please fill out all fields.")
//            accessGiven = false
//        } else {
//            accessGiven = true
//        }

        Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: self.emailField.text!, completion: { (stringArray, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                self.alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Something went wrong, please try again")
                self.accessGiven = false
            } else {
                if stringArray == nil {
                    print("No active account using this email.")
                    self.alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "There is no active account using this E-Mail.")
                    self.accessGiven = false
                    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue.SignUp.toTabBar", sender: nil)

                } else {
                    print("There is an active account using this E-mail")
                    self.accessGiven = true
                }
            }
        })

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: pwField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self.alerts(title: "Oops...", message: "Something went wrong, please try again")
                self.accessGiven = false
            } else {
                self.accessGiven = true
            }
            if let user = user {

            }
        }
        if accessGiven == true {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue.LogIn.toTabBar", sender: nil)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **accessGiven** value is true, you are performing segue to a different viewController. And so your current viewController is no longer a part of the window hierarchy. And then you are trying to present alert controllers from the completionBlocks of your **fetchProviders** and **signIn** function using `self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` where self is your viewController which is no longer a part of window hierarchy. That's why error is being thrown. To make sure, just comment your performSegue and try the same code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect! Now i guess i have to figure out how to get it to work with the `performSegue`